# Unsanitized XML from WebService, How to sanitize

Tags: c#, regex, xml, serialization

I have an **"XML"** response from a WebService which isn't sanitized. Meaning it contains **illegal characters**, **special characters**, **html tags** and **hexadecimal**.

What's the best way to sanitize this response?

Here is an Xml Example from the service.

```
<root>
 <response>
  <type>E</type>
  <code>CMNE_00034</code>
  <source>CMNQ3030</source>
  <message>some valid message here.</message>
  <detail>Error details here

   line 114:    endif 
   line 115:    edit 
   line 116: else 
 > line 117:    call LP_ACCEPT()
   line 118:    return ($status)
   line 119: endif 
   line 120: done<end of module> // invalid here

   at CMNQ3030.EXEC line 117: call LP_ACCEPT()
   at GPCSY_RUN line 5: activate INSTANCENAME."EXEC"(  ) 
   at CSYV1000.LOGON line 159: call GPCSY_RUN()
  </detail>
 </response>
</root>
```

I have tried lots of things, from creating an `XmlReader` that has settings, like this.

```
public XDocument CreateXmlDocument(string content)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(content), CreateXmlReaderSettings()))
    {
        return XDocument.Load(reader);
    }
}

private static XmlReaderSettings CreateXmlReaderSettings()
{
    return new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false };
}
```

To changing from XmlDocument to XDocument and using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` before the actual reading.

Comment: If your input "XML" be sufficiently bad, you should consider complaining to the provider.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is that it's a legacy webservice made in uniface, the service is so big that mere adjustments may cause problems, and porting it to another language will take years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely the `XMLReader`, `XDocument` etc. infrastructure in .NET will take kindly to being asked to read and parse badly formed XML.

I recommend pre-processing the XML before loading it into XML objects.

In the case above, it looks like the web service is returning an error message in the `<detail>...</detail>` element which should really be wrapped in CDATA like this:

```
<root>
 <response>
  <type>E</type>
  <code>CMNE_00034</code>
  <source>CMNQ3030</source>
  <message>some valid message here.</message>
  <detail><![CDATA[
       Error details here

       line 114:    endif 
       line 115:    edit 
       line 116: else 
     > line 117:    call LP_ACCEPT()
       line 118:    return ($status)
       line 119: endif 
       line 120: done<end of module> // invalid here

       at CMNQ3030.EXEC line 117: call LP_ACCEPT()
       at GPCSY_RUN line 5: activate INSTANCENAME."EXEC"(  ) 
       at CSYV1000.LOGON line 159: call GPCSY_RUN()
   ]]>
  </detail>
 </response>
</root>
```

You should be able to pretty quickly knock together a parser to find, extract and wrap the text between the end of the `<detail>` tag and the start of the `</detail>` tag within a `<[CDATA[` and `]]>` tags.

Of course, there may be other fields in your service's XML that also contain either string data or malformed characters etc. and you'll likely need to find and replace these characters with, for example, regular expressions, etc.

Once corrected, you should have no difficulty loading the clean XML into XMLDocuments/XDocuments etc.

HTH.